# Finding the antiderivative of $\exp(\cos(z))$ on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Does this function have an antiderivative on the complex plane?  How can this be proven?  And if it does, how can we compute it?

Comment: Lagrange inversion?

Comment: That's not something I have.  I'm looking for a way to do this without using series.

Comment: Not even power series?

Answer (score 2):

The function $e^{\cos(z)}$ doesn't have an antiderivative that can be expressed by an elementary formula (in fact, this is already true on the real line).

Comment: I see.  But it does work for $exp(sin(z))$?

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski That function also doesn't have an elementary antiderivative. The two are related by $z\mapsto z+\tfrac{\pi}2$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\exp(\cos(z))$ has a holomorphic anti-derivative since it is holomorphic on a simply-connected domain. After fixing some arbitrary point $w_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, the anti-derivative can be expressed formally by

$$ f(w) = \int_{w_0}^{w} \exp(\cos(z)) \, dz $$

where the integration is done over an arbitrary path connecting an  $w_0$ with $w$.

Answer (score 2):

$z\mapsto\exp \cos z$ is an entire function, so its integral along a path from $a\in\mathbb C$ to $b\in\mathbb C$ does not depend on which path from $a$ to $b$ is followed.  Hence we can define
$$
F(z) = \int\limits_\text{some path from 0 to $z$} \exp\cos u \, du.
$$
Then $F'(z) = \exp\cos z$.